# Issue outputting php array of links to jQuery backstretch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I'm using jQuery [Backstretch](https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch) to load a gallery on a page. I'm now trying to make the gallery pull in images from content uploaded via [custom meta boxes](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box/).

Here's the working script with hard-coded image links. All I'm doing is passing an array of links to images to backstretch, and it does the rest:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#main').backstretch([
      "wp-content/themes/themename/assets/graphics/image1.jpg",
      "wp-content/themes/themename/assets/graphics/image2.jpg",
      "wp-content/themes/themename/assets/graphics/image3.jpg",
      "wp-content/themes/themename/assets/graphics/image4.jpg",
    ], {
    fade: 1000,
    duration: 7000
  });
});
```

And here's my attempt at replacing the hard-coded images with those pulled in from the custom meta. The php function outputs an array of links pulled from the custom meta:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#main').backstretch([
      "<?php $images = rwmb_meta( 'jb_meta_page_bkg_img', 'type=image_advanced' );
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {
          echo $image['full_url'];
      } ?>"
    ], {
    fade: 1000,
    duration: 7000
  });
});
```

This doesn't work – backstretch loads, but the whole array is outputted as the source attribute for the first image!

Can anyone see where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest building the needed array in php and use json_encode().

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#main').backstretch(
      <?php 
        $images = rwmb_meta('jb_meta_page_bkg_img', 'type=image_advanced');
        $result = array();
        foreach ($images as $image) {
          $result[] = $image['full_url'];
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
      ?>, {
    fade: 1000,
    duration: 7000
  });
});
```

Comment: Just done some further testing, and am getting no images loading on iPhone. Have now posted this as a seperate issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489419/images-not-loading-on-iphone-when-pulled-in-via-array-json-encode

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('#main').backstretch([
      "<?php $images = rwmb_meta( 'jb_meta_page_bkg_img', 'type=image_advanced' );
        echo implode('", "', $images); ?>"
    ], {
    fade: 1000,
    duration: 7000
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks – tried but no luck. This just outputs the word "Array" as the source output, not the url itself. I need to use `$image['full_url'];` to get the correct url for each image, but not sure how to add that in  to what you've suggested.